# Java: Recursively search an array for an integer given an array, integer, and array length

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive method that accepts an int array, number of elements in the array, and an integer, and returns whether the integer is present as an element in the array.I just can't figure out why I this isn't working for all my test cases. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
public static boolean search(int[] findIn, int target, int len){
    if(len == 0){
        return false;
    }else if(findIn[len-1] == target){
        return true;
    }else{
        return search(findIn, target, len-1);
    }   
}
```

Yes I realize there are better ways other than recursion to do this, but it is required that I do it this way.

My main method looks like this: I'm just hard-coding it for the time being:

```
int[] arr = {1};
System.out.println(search(arr,1,1));
```

Testcases:
[image]

Comment: For which test cases?

Comment: You don't need a parameter for the array's length. If you have the array then you have it's length.

Comment: It looks correct at first sight. What's the failing test case?

Comment: @Takendarkk And how would you recurse without this third parameter?

Comment: @Takendarkk It's not the length actually, but the index to look at. Would worth renaming.

Comment: @Joel I do believe "_number of elements in the array_" is length. I don't see how it would be the index to look at. If that were true and the element to look for was at index 0, this method would never find it. I must really be misunderstanding something here.

Comment: are you sure in your test-cases you are sending the correct value of len every-time ? why not send arr.length when you first call it, just to be sure

Comment: I just tested it, and it returns what is expected (true). No issue here.

Comment: @Takendarkk the initial call uses the length indeed. Subsequent recursive calls use (length - n)

Comment: Regarding your testcases results, this is certainly not the code that you posted which generates this outputs.

Comment: If you're 'just hard coding it for the time being', where are those test results coming from? I've tested them all and your posted code works fine.

Comment: Agree. Those test results are wrong. The code works fine. len iterates from the highest index down to the lowest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am almost certain, that your method parameters are in the wrong order:

Your results hint that you switched the 2nd and 3rd parameter!

Maybe this

```
static boolean search(int[] findIn, int target, int len)
```

should actually be

```
static boolean search(int[] findIn, int len, int target)
```

Comment: You're right, it seems to explain all test cases. Good one!

Comment: Hi, @luuksen, I made that improvement, but it still seems to give me the same results.

Comment: Hey! This method signature definitely does not return the same results, when your method calls didn't change. (or those of your test application)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, that code should work fine so I suspect your problem lies in your test cases rather than here.

One thing I will mention is that use of `if-return-else` constructs tend to complicate your code unnecessarily.

It's usually better to avoid that with something like:

```
public static boolean search(
    int[] findIn, int target, int len)
{
    if (len == 0)
        return false;
    if (findIn[len-1] == target)
        return true;
    return search(findIn, target, len-1);
}
```

I find that a lot easier to follow at a glance than trying to track what `if` clause I happen to be in at any given moment.

In any case, both it and your version perform fine, at least for small test cases. The first time you pass in a ten-million-element array is probably when you'll discover it's not the *best* poster child for recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this and it is working..
I am using a static instance variable to find the position of number in array.
In stead of returning the position of number you can modify to return a boolean

```
public class RecSearch {
    static int pos=0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = {1};
        System.out.println(recSearch(a, 0));
        System.out.println(recSearch(a, 1));
    }
    public static int recursiveSearch(int[] arr, int numtoSearch) {
        if (pos>=arr.length) {
            pos=0;
            return -1;
        }
        if (arr[pos]==numtoSearch)
            return (pos+1);
        else {
            pos++;
            return recursiveSearch(arr, numtoSearch);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {
    
    public static boolean checkNumber(int input[], int x) {
        
        return check(input,x,0);
    }
    
    public static boolean check(int input[],int x,int start){
        if(start==input.length)
            return false;
        if(input[start]==x)
            return true;
        return check(input,x,start+1);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Check Number in Array using Recursion in Java